# Problem when solving for $\lambda$ in applying Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having a hard time solving for $\lambda$ for the two equations below.
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=26\lambda x-10\lambda y$$ and $$\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=26\lambda y-10\lambda x.$$

I keep getting  $\lambda=0$ after trying to solve the equations simultaneously. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe $\lambda =0$ is the solution.

Need a succinct guideline to this.

---

Original question

Find the maximum and minimum value of ${\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ when $13x^2-10xy+13y^2=72$

Comment: Can you post that original problem? And where is the third equation?

Comment: You will need three equations!!!

Comment: All I want to know is how would you go about solving these two equations for λ simultaneously. It's all algebra from here.

Comment: But so is the problem wrong!

Comment: From the first and second equation we get $$x=y$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please check the edited question.

Comment: Write $$13(x^2+y^2)-10xy=72$$ and square the objective function.

Comment: If you're saying that x=y, then what's the value of λ? Finding the value of λ is crucial

Comment: when you see a square root, it is always easier to find the max and min of $x^2 + y^2$ instead.

Comment: @ArcticChar Doesn't answer my question precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the same as optimizing $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ subject to $g(x,y)=13x^2-10xy+13y^2-72=0$. Applying Lagrange multipliers we can set up the following equations: $$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x=\lambda(26x-10y)=\lambda \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y=\lambda (26y-10x)=\lambda \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\\
13x^2-10xy+13y^2=72
\end{cases}$$
Solving these equations, we get $\lambda =\frac18$ or $\lambda =\frac{1}{18}$ (these equations should be easily solvable compared to your original equations). We can directly see that the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)$ subject to $g(x,y)=0$ are $9$ and $4$ respectively, meaning that the maximum and minimum values of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{f(x,y)}$ are $3$ and $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you at least show how you arrive at those λ values?

Comment: @user3187800 divide the first equation by the second and express $y$ in terms of $x$, then substitute into the third equation

Comment: @user3187800 How are you getting those values? I'm getting $x =+- \frac{3}{sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @user3187800 you're right, just calculate the corresponding values of $y$ and $x^2+y^2$

Comment: If the critical points are $(\frac{3}{\sqrt2},\frac{3}{\sqrt2}), (-\frac{3}{\sqrt2},-\frac{3}{\sqrt2})$
For the minimum to be $4$, I should have a critical point $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, am I wrong?

Comment: why do your points only have a single coordinate?

Comment: After getting $x=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}, x=-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$, where should I plug these values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126841/discussion-between-5201314-and-user3187800).